# Cannot Enable Integration Features on VPC on a Domain

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Hi I'm running virtual Windows Vista within Windows 7 Pro. In order to do copy and paste between the two OS's I click Tools/Enable Integration Features in the VPC. It brings up a login box with: DOMAIN\Username (where Domain is my workplace domain and Username my username).

If I enter my domain password (the one I use for Win 7), login fails, if I use the VPC passowrd login fails. If I click "Use another account", it brings up a new User name/Password box but Domain is still set to that of my workplace and can't seem to be altered and I can't login with any combination of credentials.

Enable at startup option is already on.

Any ideas how I can enable the Integration Features?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Use another account", in the "User name" field you can type your virtual machine computer name and use the "\" and then your user name that you would use to log on to your virtual machine.

This should change the "Domain: xxx" to the one that you entered before the backslash in the "User name" field. Then enter your password, the one for the user located on your virtual machine and not the host.